# Add ASP.NET 2015 form data to SqlDataSource

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Using Visual Studio 2015 I have created a web form with basic form information such as name. On this page I also have a SqlDataconnection that connects to a database in the project as well. The problem I am having is how do I take what the user has inserted into the form and save it to the database? I have tried SqlDataConnection.Insert() on the Submit button but get an error that the input type is incorrect. The data is supposed to be displayed to a GridView on another page, is the SqlDataConnection supposed to go there instead?
I'll display a  form item and then the onclick event I am attempting in the aspx.vb

"

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    CardCollectionDataSource.Insert()
```

End Sub

When I click the submit button to insert the datasource data, I get an error that the input string is incorrect.

Comment: It would be a good idea to show the relevant parts of the code you have written, and also give proper details of any errors you get, and exactly when they occur, so that people can help you. Based on just a prose description, we are mainly going to be guessing - imagine you asked your mechanic to fix the car without looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Somewhere I messed up the functionality, simply deleted the SQL data connection and gridview as well as the database, recreated them and it worked perfectly with the insert method I posted above!